# ENUM and Sorting in an arraylist

Tags: sorting, kotlin, enums

I wanna sort an array list which has name of days like `["Sat","Mon", "Wed",  "Fri", "Sun"]`. I wanna sort it by ENUM like:

```
public enum DayInWeek {
   Sat, Sun, Mon, Tus, Wed, Thu, Fri
}
```

How can I do that?

Searching on web. could not find satisfying answer.

```
internal enum class WeekDayEnum {
  Mon,
  Tue,
  Wed,
  Thu,
  Fri,
  Sat,
  Sun
}

inner class DayCompare(var days: WeekDayEnum) : Comparable<DayCompare> {

    override fun compareTo(s1: DayCompare): Int {
      return if (s1.days.ordinal < this.days.ordinal)
        1
      else if (s1.days.ordinal > this.days.ordinal)
        -1
      else 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing by ordinal is the default comparable behaviour of an enum. You can therefore sort your list like this:

```
val dayList = listOf("Sat","Mon", "Wed", "Fri", "Sun")

// Gives: [Mon, Wed, Fri, Sat, Sun]
val ordered = dayList.map(WeekDayEnum::valueOf).sorted()
```

Comment: Really appreciate your answer!